# What each piece of this command does: du /home | sort -nr +0 -1 | head -10

Tags: unix

I have the command:

```
du /home | sort -nr +0 -1 | head -10
```

and need to know what each piece ("du", "/home", "|", "sort", "-nr", "+0", "-1", "head", and "10") does.

Comment: have you considered the power of man?

Comment: Well, i can get the du, /home, sort, -nr, and head.... i just dont know what the numbers do.  Also, i'm just assuming the pipes, "|", are just a way to run 3 separate commands at once... ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
du /home
```

gives a list of the "Disk Usage" (thus the name of the command) of every directory in /home and, recursively, all sub-directories. One line output per directory. "|" sends the output to the next command.

```
sort
```

Sorts the result, with "-n" specifying numeric (as opposed to lexicographic) sort, "r" specifies reverse order so the largest value appears first). "-nr" is equivalent to "-n -r"

```
head -10
```

Outputs only the first 10 lines of the previous command.

In essence it's finding the 10 largest directories in /home.

Answer (score 3):

```
du /home
```

du - Disk Usage

Command gives result of disk usage for `/home` directory in KB

`|` known as pipe; for feeding the output data to next command (sort)

```
sort -nr +0 -1
```

OPTION MEANING:

> interpreting sorting keys
>   alphabetically or numerically (-n
>   option)
>
> in ascending or descending order  (-r
>   -- sort in reverse option)
>
> -n (numeric keys sorting)
>
> +n (sorting using n-th field, counting from zero)

sort - sorting the result (see man pages for sort to find what those option does)

```
head -10
```

Finally it results the top 10 records

Answer (score 1):

du /home shows disk usage for every directory on the /home area of your disk.
sort -nr +0 -1 performs a reverse numeric sort on its input (which comes from the du command).
head -10 shows the first 10 lines of its input (which comes from the sort command).

man *xxx* shows you the manual for command *xxx*. For example, `man du`, `man sort`, and `man head`.